# How to turn off the database console when opening a table?

Tags: php, phpstorm

When I open any table in "Database" view, the Database Console opens with query executed. However, I don't need to see every SELECT when I just want to lookup into my table.

How can I turn off this behaviour? As I remember, in 2017.3 version the database console doesn't opened automatically.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/working-with-database-consoles.html seems here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue will be fixed in next IDE update. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-6175 & latest comment there

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a proper solution to your problem, but I can suggest a workaround.

The first time you will do a select (simple double click) to your table, the *Database Console* will be opened, once is open you click on the top right icon to hide it

[image]

In order to let it stay hidden, you must have at least one tab opened.
Now if you will try to open another table the console will stay closed.

Hope it helps.